# Insert LocalDateTime with MongoTemplate in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb, spring-mongodb, localdatetime

I'm saving a simple java object to Azure Cosmos DB ( mongo API ) from a spring boot application, using mongoTemplate. The insert works, but I'm having some problem with the dates; my object has a LocalDateTime property: when I save the object to my local MongoDB (NO COSMOS) the date appears like this:

```
"timestamp": 2022-08-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
```

Instead, when I save the object to Cosmos db, the date appears like this:

```
"timestamp" : {
    "$date" : 1659305160000
},
```

What I want is to save the date in the same format as MongoDB also on Cosmos.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's the same, just your application displays it different.

Comment: how you are storing it?

Comment: What do you mean? I have a custom object, and I'm saving it using the save method of MongoTemplate; I'm not sure this is the answer of your question